# Tkinter link button press and 'return' key

Tags: function, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I've looked at various tutorials for how to link a button press *and* a keyboard press of 'return.' I can do them both, but only one at a time. The keyboard style is `rootWindow.bind('<Return>' functionName` and that linking an on-screen button is `command=functionName`. I just can't get them to work when used at the same time.

This is the very basic skeleton of what I'm working with

```
def printthis(event):
    print("worked")

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Return>', printthis)

button1 = Button(root, text='Enter', command=printthis)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I get this error when I run the current code, I'm just not sure what 'event' I should pass into the `command=printthis` section

`TypeError: printthis() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`

As a side note I am using Python 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind a function an event object will be passed into it whenever the binding action occurs. If you want your function to work for both on event and button press then you have two options.

First is if your function may require the event object. Then allow your function to take an optional argument for event.

```
def printthis(event = None):
    if event is None:
        # handle this case

    # otherwise handle event object normally.
```

The second is if you don't care about the event object then the 1st is still fine (you just never use the event parameter), or you can use `lambda` when binding.

```
def printthis():
    print("worked")

root.bind('<Return>', lambda e: printthis())
```

`lambda` takes `e` which is the event object and then calls your function without passing in `e` discarding it.